# Error reading previous json file; "*.json was not found."

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Looking to resolve an issue with this basic BigQuery script run from local machine. The credentials line keeps looking for a previous json file that I deleted and created /inserted a new one. I wanted to get this script working before applying the connection to my other app. I have the bigquery user role and permissions set for the dataset. The json and requirements files are in the same directory as the script.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
"web-app-341703-b9f22cbc7c7e.json")

client = bigquery.Client()

QUERY = (
'SELECT * FROM "hosp_info.hospital_general_information"'
'FROM state = "TX"'
'LIMIT 10')
query_job = client.query(QUERY)
rows = query_job.result()

for row in rows:
  print(row.name)
```

requirements file (I believe I have all the necessary packages):

```
cachetools==5.0.0
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
google-api-core==2.5.0
google-api-python-client==2.37.0
google-auth==2.6.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.54.0
httplib2==0.20.4
idna==3.3
oauth2-client==1.2.1
protobuf==3.19.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pyparsing==3.0.7
requests==2.27.1
rsa==4.8
six==1.16.0
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.8
```

I tried just the filename and the full path to the file but still the same error message:

google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File db-web-app-324216-59de47eb637a.json was not found.

I've searched for answers and found none. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "8.json was not found." supposed to read "*.json was not found."

Comment: What line is throwing the error?  Could the error be coming from the line which creates `client`?  Look for any environment variables that maybe set that point to your old JSON file.  In your code, I am not actually seeing you use the `credentials` variable.

Comment: Forgot to do that. I saw this run in a terminal but can be included in the script:

Comment: Thanks for your help. I hit the enter button for carriage return. So the env variable is export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="<path/to/json file>" right? Ran that line in terminal, then ran script again and got new error message which I really don't get: google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT Signature.'}). I presume I changed the course and it's now looking at the new json file in the script. What would the credentials variable look like?

Comment: I think we are now heading down a different (but valid) question path.  If I'm reading the question correctly, you now have a very different error message and a different story at this time.  I'd be tempted to suggest that you either radically update the question or (and my recommendation) create a whole new question with complete details describing the new situation.  Better to create separate questions than massive questions that wander around :-)